# Twitter Web Intent - Change Order Of Text, Url & Hashtag?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to set up a Twitter share url but it seems to reformat what I'm adding to the url when posting.

**What I want:**

> Hey! Check out the latest #JamesBond DVD at www.example.com

**Code:**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hey!  Check out the latest #JamesBond DVD at www.example.com" target="_blank">Tweet-The format I want</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hey!  Check out the latest &hashtags=JamesBond DVD at &url=http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Tweet-Kind Of Half Works - Puts the URL in the wrong place..</a>
```

**What I'm getting:**

> Hey! Check out the latest
>
> Hey! Check out the latest http://www.example.com/ #JamesBond DVD at

**I've fiddled what I have here:** https://jsfiddle.net/qnaqmhhL/1/

The format I want is - Text >> Hashtag >> Text >> URL

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

You need to [URI Encode the special characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  So, for example `#` becomes `%23`.

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hey!%20Check%20out%20the%20latest%20%23JamesBond%20DVD%20at%20www.example.com

Clicking on that link will populate the Tweet in the format you want.

Comment: So in short, passing all into the text parameter. Good idea. Thx